# How to get the value from new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID)?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal.js

This is my first experience with MSAL.js.

In Azure AD B2C I'm trying to get the value from the userid that is entered into popup login screen generate by a signin policy which is called from an html file.

var clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, function (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
            // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
        });

```
    function login() {
        clientApplication = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, applicationConfig.authority, function (errorDesc, token, error, tokenType) {
            // Called after loginRedirect or acquireTokenPopup
        });
        clientApplication.loginPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes, "login_hint=user@domain.com").then(function (idToken) {
            clientApplication.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                updateUI();
            }, function (error) {
                clientApplication.acquireTokenPopup(applicationConfig.b2cScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                    updateUI();
                }, function (error) {
                    logMessage("Error acquiring the popup:\n" + error);
                });
            })
        }, function (error) {
            reset();
            logMessage("Error during login:\n" + error);
        });
```

The user is entering userid@domain.com   I need to retrieve this value so that I can parse out the domain name.

How to extract the userid?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getUser‎()` to extract the userid. For the details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa).